# Consuming an API on localhost from a node-chrome-debug docker image

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver

I am running a REST API in a container started from a [node-chrome-debug](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome-debug) image and I am trying to consume it from a Selenium Webdriver script executed on the node. However, when I try to hit the API on `http:\\localhost:5000` via RestSharp, I receive the following message:

```
 Error: 'Connection refused [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:5000 (127.0.0.1:5000)'
```

The configuration of docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
version: "3"
services:
        selenium-hub:
                image: selenium/hub
                ports:
                        - "4444:4444"
                environment:
                        GRID_MAX_SESSION: 2
                        GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 300
                        GRID)TIMEOUT: 300
        chrome:
                image: selenium/node-chrome-debug

                depends_on:
                        - selenium-hub
                environment:
                        HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: selenium-hub
                        HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
                        NODE_MAX_SESSION: 2
                        NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 2
```

I suspect that the REST client is hitting the Selenium Grid Hub instead of the container's localhost. Is there a way to connect to the correct machine? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am running a REST service on a docker container as a way to communicate with system's kernel and run a couple of commands (System.Diagnostics.Process isn't working for me).

Comment: What made you think the application is running on port 5000? There is nothing about port 5000 in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Oh, the API runs over Flask whose default port on development mode is 5000. Once it is up, I can consume the REST service using cURL on the node's terminal. It's just Selenium who can't access localhost:5000. Being that said, I can choose another port, such as 8000, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Flask. But if you Flask is reachable from localhost:5000 (the host), that does not mean that Selenium, which is running _in_ a Container can reach 5000. Wold guess here, but you might need to put the Flask API in the same Docker Network as Selenium is running and expose the 5000 port there.  And from the standpoint of Selenium Container there is nothing on localhost (its own container) and port 5000. If you specify flask-service as "flask" and expose 5000, then flask is reacheable for Selenium on http://flask:5000/.